# Orientation of three points in 3D space

Tags: geometry, 3d

How to find the orientation of three vertices A, B and C of a plane in 3D  are in clockwise, anticlockwise or collinear? 
I find this below link in 2D

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/orientation-3-ordered-points/

I have tried in 3D, but I am not sure about this.
**dot(n, cross(A-C, B-C))**
where n is normal to a plane.

If the result is positive, B is counterclockwise from A; if it's negative, B is clockwise from A.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the result dependant on definition of "normal vector $n$ to a plane $A,B,C$" ?

Comment: in 3D if you watch from one side they are clockwise, from the other side counterclockwise.

Comment: The formula you've used -- with the dot and cross product -- is correct. Try it with $A = (0,0,0), B  = (1, 0, 0), C = (0, 1, 0)$, and normal vector $n = (0,0,1)$ to see that the postive result does indeed correspond to "counterclockwise as viewed from the endpoint of $n$, looking toward the basepoint of $n$."

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your three points are $\vec{p}_1 = ( x_1 , y_1 , z_1 )$, $\vec{p}_2 = ( x_2 , y_2 , z_2 )$, and $\vec{p}_3 = ( x_3 , y_3 , z_3 )$.

Let
$$\vec{n} = \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \times \left ( \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \right )$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
x_n = (y_2 - y_1) (z_3 - z_1) - (z_2 - z_1) (y_3 - y_1) \\
y_n = (z_2 - z_1) (x_3 - x_1) - (x_2 - x_1) (z_3 - z_1) \\
z_n = (x_2 - x_1) (y_3 - y_1) - (y_2 - y_1) (x_3 - x_1) \end{cases} $$
If the three points are collinear, then $\vec{n} = ( 0 , 0 , 0 ) = 0$. Otherwise, the three points are on a plane, with $\vec{n}$ being normal (perpendicular) to the plane.

As mentioned in a comment, if we look at the triangle from the side the normal vector $\vec{n}$ points to, the points are in counterclockwise order; but, if we look at the triangle from the other side, they are in clockwise order.

If we know that the three points are on a plane with normal vector $\vec{k}$, then
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{k} \cdot \vec{n} = \vec{k} \cdot \left ( \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \times \left ( \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \right ) \gt 0, & \text{ counterclockwise } \\
\vec{k} \cdot \vec{n} = \vec{k} \cdot \left ( \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \times \left ( \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \right ) \lt 0, & \text{ clockwise } \\
\vec{k} \cdot \vec{n} = \vec{k} \cdot \left ( \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \times \left ( \vec{p}_3 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \right ) = 0, & \text{ oops } \end{cases}$$

The *"oops"* case covers several possible situations. For example, if the three points are collinear, then $\vec{n} = 0$. Or, if the three points are on a plane parallel to $\vec{k}$, the result is zero also.